# What exactly does v-bind:css="false" do, and where is it documented?

Tags: vue.js

The Vue docs for [JavaScript Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html?#JavaScript-Hooks) mention:

> It’s ... a good idea to explicitly add `v-bind:css="false"` for JavaScript-only transitions so that Vue can skip the CSS detection. This also prevents CSS rules from accidentally interfering with the transition.

1. Are there official docs for `v-bind:css` somewhere? (*Note - I know what the [`v-bind` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) does*)
2. What does "CSS detection" mean exactly, and where in the source is this done?
3. What's an example of a CSS rule that would interfere with a transition, and technically how does this directive prevent that from happening?

The only other place I've seen this mentioned is in the Vue source code tests at [`vue/test/unit/features/transition/transition.spec.js`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/2.6/test/unit/features/transition/transition.spec.js#L388), but as far as I can tell that test doesn't really check anything related to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Are there official docs?

I haven't found any official docs for :css anywhere other than what you already found.

## 2. What does it do?

Investigating this myself, "CSS detection" is probably the wrong phrase, IMO it should read something like:

> It’s ... a good idea to explicitly add v-bind:css="false" for JavaScript-only transitions so that Vue can skip **applying the transition classes**. This also prevents CSS rules from accidentally interfering with the transition.

The :css attribute is actually quite simple. It essentially turns on/off the adding of the **v-enter, v-enter-to, v-leave, v-leave-to** classes to the element being transitioned. We can see that in `transition-util.js` from the Vue source:

**transition-util.js**

```js
if (def.css !== false) {
  extend(res, autoCssTransition(def.name || 'v'))
}
```

...

```js
const autoCssTransition: (name: string) => Object = cached(name => {
  return {
    enterClass: `${name}-enter`,
    enterToClass: `${name}-enter-to`,
    enterActiveClass: `${name}-enter-active`,
    leaveClass: `${name}-leave`,
    leaveToClass: `${name}-leave-to`,
    leaveActiveClass: `${name}-leave-active`
  }
})
```

So if the **css** attribute is not set to false and the transition has a **name** attribute then this code will apply `${name}-enter`, otherwise it applys `v-enter`.

## 3. Example Interference

Personally I have experienced interference when using custom hooks on the transition-group to apply custom classes. for example:

```
<transition-group @enter="enterHook">...
```

```
methods: {
  enterHook (el) {
    el.classList.add('custom-enter-class')
  }
}
```

Without the `:css="false"` attribute I experienced strange and inconsistent behaviour when adding/removing classes programmatically. This attribute made things much more robust.